# Can I SINTERSTORE with one of input keys as the destination safely?

Tags: redis

If I run:

```
SADD friends "mike"
SADD enemies "mike" "john"
SINTERSTORE friends friends enemies
```

It works, but is that valid and guaranteed to succeed?

If it is valid, it is also for the other commands ending in STORE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can safely use one of the source keys as the destination for the STORE commands.